# How to pass a flask/jinja2 variable to a js script?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to write a script that gets the username from the flask app and automatically renders it to a template. Basically i have this line in **layout.html** :

```
<div class="sidebar-heading" id= "my_username"> {% block sidebar %} Start Bootsrap {% endblock %} </div>
```

Then **index.html** that is my main page gets the username:

```
{% block sidebar %} {{ username }} {% endblock %}
 <script src= "static/js/user_name.js"> </script>
```

I want to store that data in the js and print it to other templates. **user_name.js** :

```
var username = document.getElementById('my_username').innerHTML;

document.querySelector("#insert_user").innerHTML = username.innerHTML
```

When i pass that value to a new template :

```
 {% block sidebar %}
     <div id = "insert_user" > </div>
    {% endblock %}
<script src= "static/js/user_name.js"> </script>
```

The output printed to the new html page says "undefined"

What did i do wrong?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, putting

```
<script>var username = "{{ username }}";</script>
```

in your base template should make that available to scripts in other templates.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i forgot my programing basics. I managed to sove te problem by making **get_userName.js**

```
  //get the username
var username = document.getElementById('my_username').innerHTML;

//store the username
myStorage = window.localStorage;
myStorage.setItem("Username",username)
```

and **post_userName.js**

```
// function to load a script
function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = jsFilePath;

    document.body.appendChild(js);
}

includeJs("static/js/get_userName.js");


    //update the sidebar username
    username = localStorage.getItem('Username')
    document.querySelector("#my_username").innerHTML = username
```